# $a^2=3b$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for the roots of $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$ to constitute an equilateral triangle.

Tags: complex-numbers

The three roots of the equation $x^{3}+ax^{2}+bx+c=0$ (where $a, b, c$ are given complex numbers) are represented on the Argand diagram by the points $A, B, C$. Prove that $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle if and only if $a^{2}=3b$.
Could someone help me to prove the **converse** part?

Let $z_1, z_2, z_3$ be the roots of the given equation.
$z_1 + z_2 + z_3 = -a$ and $z_1z_2 + z_2z_3 + z_3z_1=b$.
Using interior angle of an equilateral triangle is $\frac {\pi}{3}$.
$(z_1-z_3)(z_1-z_2)=(z_2-z_3)(z_3-z_2)$ gives $a^{2}=3b$.

May I have some sort of working out to prove the converse of the given result?

Comment: Hint : 3 complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$ form an equilateral triangle if and only if $z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2=z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_3z_1$.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify the title of your question in order for it to reflect the content of the question. Do you agree ?

Comment: Jean, that's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that $a^2=3b$. Replacing $b$ by

$$b=\frac{a^2}{3}$$

into the third degree equation, it becomes:

$$\left(x+\frac{a}{3}\right)^3=-c \tag{1}$$

Let $d$ be a cubic root of $-c$ (assumed nonzero). Then (1) can be written under the form:

$$\left(\underbrace{\frac{x+\frac{a}{3}}{d}}_Z\right)^3=1\tag{2}$$

The solutions to equation (2)

- in terms of variable $Z$, are the three third roots of unity, giving rise to the "canonical" equilateral triangle $1,e^{2i \pi/3}, e^{4i \pi/3}$.
- in terms of variable $x$, are images of the previous ones by transformation $x=dZ-\frac{a}{3}$ which preserves in particular angles, giving as well an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Once more an anonymous downvoter for a neat answer (so I think...). What a plague on this site ! Downvoting shouldn't be anonymous.